# How small can a particle of iron be and still be magnetic?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Any piece of iron that you can hold in your hand will be attracted to a magnet. I suspect a single atom would not. So is there a lower limit to the size of a particle of iron that would still react to a magnetic field?

Comment: Do you know what [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)) is?

Comment: A single atom of iron has magnetic properties, but obviously it can not have [magnetic domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain), and so it probably would not make sense to call a single atom a "permanent magnet." What property are you thinking of when you say, "still be magnetic?"

Comment: Even an electron or a proton has a magnetic dipole moment.

Answer (score 0):

Very good question. These small pieces of materials are called clusters (containing maybe 10-100 atoms) and people do serious research to find how magnetic moments of these clusters change with the cluster size. For example, you might look for articles containing words "clusters" and "magnetism" in their titles.